# How Create Yii2 RESTful API

Tags: api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want To create Anew API To Use It on app i have web site and want to make API for it, where i should create an API in Frontend Or Backend OR create anew module same frontend level ???

and How I can Create A Module in Yii2 ??

Comment: Normally API not require website frontend prefer backend and follow [this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create a separate module for API.

Please follow below link to learn how to create module.

[How to create Modules in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html)

And for RESTful Web Services follow :

[RestApi with yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)